# string has no member named 'subtr' error

Tags: c++, string, subtraction

Thank you for reading. I am making a script to read a birthday in this format: month/day/year, and separate the year, day, and month. I got the year part, but for the day part, I am trying to subtract the position values of the second '/' and the final position value using string.subtr(,). So, for example, I am trying to get 01/26 from 01/26/1994 in the findDay() function.
But I seem to get the "string has no member named 'subtr'"  error on line 55. Can someone please guide me, as I am a completely new programmer. Also, thank you for your continued help since I have doubled my knowledge after receiving input from this site.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void findYear(string &);
void findDay (string &);
void findMonth(string &);
int main()
{
    string birthday;
    cout << "Enter birthday: " << endl; // 01/26/1994
    cin >> birthday;
    string year = birthday;
    string day = birthday;
    string month = birthday;
    findYear(year);
    cout << year << endl;
    findDay(day);
    cout << day << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
    int slashpos = birthday.find('/');

}

void findYear(string &year)
{
    int slashpos = year.find('/');
    int i = 0;
    string temp2;
while(year.at(year.length()-1-i)!='/')
    {
        temp2 += year.at(year.length()-1-i);
        i++;
    }
        string rtemp2 = "";
        for(int k = 0; k < temp2.length(); k++)
        {
            rtemp2 += temp2.at(temp2.length()-1-k);
            year = rtemp2; 
        }

}
void findDay (string &day)
{
    string tempday1 = "";
    string temp2 = "";
    int i = 0;
    tempday1 = day.subtr(day.rfind('/'),day.length()-1); /* error here! [Error] 'std::string' has no member named 'subtr'*/
    while(tempday1.at(tempday1.length()-1-i)!='/')
    {
        temp2 += tempday1.at(tempday1.length()-1-i);
        i++;
    }
        string rtemp2 = "";
        for(int k = 0; k < tempday1.length(); k++)
        {
            rtemp2 += tempday1.at(tempday1.length()-1-k);
            day = rtemp2; 
        }
}
```

Comment: You need `std::string::substr`.

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  it's a good question, the code has a simple mistake, the answer solves it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `substr` with a 2nd `s`. SUB-**S**TRing.